# SSL handshake with Firebase Realtime DB stopped working sequentially to a Blaze plan issue (ESP8266-Firebase communication)

Tags: ssl, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage, at-command, esp8266wifi

**Some background to the current events:** in June we upgraded our Firebase project to Blaze plan.

At the beginning of July, we were charged $0.01 for Cloud Storage. For some reason, the payment didn't go through and we got a Firebase warning that the services are at risk of suspension. We resolved the issue by entering a different credit number (Firebase confirmed).

We are currently working on an IoT project that communicates with Firebase Realtime DB via a WiFi module ESP8266.
The communication has been great for the last 5 months, and every change we did was thoroughly tested. But for some reason since the credit problem, aside from a few individual occasions, the SSL handshake with Firebase has failed repeatedly.

We realize there might be an underlying problem in our code that did not cause an issue up until now, but the current events seem highly circumstantial.

**Does anyone know, is there something connected to the SSL handshake that might have changed due to the credit problem? Is there anything we should be refreshing in Firebase?**

The communication is established using AT Commands.
***This is what we are getting now:***

> AT+CIPSSLSIZE=4096
>
> OK
>  AT+CIPSTART="SSL","project-host.firebaseio.com",443
>
> ERROR
>  CLOSED

***This is what we got up until the credit  problem:***

> AT+CIPSSLSIZE=4096
>
> OK
>  AT+CIPSTART="SSL", "project-host.firebaseio.com" ,443
>  CONNECT
>
> OK

**Note: we checked a TCP connection with a different host - it worked.
Any advice would be highly appreciated!**

Comment: *firebaser here* All databases run on the exact same infrastructure, no matter what plan you're on. If you think there's a regression in Firebase's behavior, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. They'll want an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I recommend including that straight away too.

Comment: Thank you for your response! we already reached out to Firebase (yesterday), we should probably add the MCVE as you recommended. the reason we posted a question here, as well is because a project final due date is in two days

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In another forum someone informed us that: "Firebase switched to TLS 1.2 and AT firmware doesn't support it". Can you please confirm the switch? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the forum in that case?

Comment: Here is the link, but in order to see it you need to login: [https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22962&e=0](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22962&e=0) (we didn't find a way to make it public). Thanks! @FrankvanPuffelen